# Java - Instance method for specific generic instances

Tags: java, types, generics

can I make a method that works on specific type of a generic class.

For example, I have my class below:

```
package utils;

public class MyArray<T> {
    // Constants
    private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 10;

    // Instance Fields
    private T[] elms;
    private int size;

    // Constructor
    public MyArray () {
        elms = (T[]) new Object[INITIAL_SIZE];
        size = 0;
    }

    // Methods
    public void add (T elm) {
        if (elms.length == size)
            increaseSize();

        elms[size++] = elm;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        String str = "[" + elms[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            str += ", " + elms[i];

        str += "]";

        return str;
    }

    // Helper Methods
    private void increaseSize () {
        T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[elms.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            temp[i] = elms[i];

        elms = (T[]) new Object[2 * temp.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            elms[i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

Can I make a method that will work on `MyArray<Integer>` or `MyArray<Long>` and throws an exception on other types?

I tried doing the following:

```
public T sumOfElms () {
    if (T instanceof Integer) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas or thoughts on how I can do it?

Comment: Why do you want that? The generic types should already make these runtime checks unnecessary. You cannot limit `T` to "Integer or Long", but you could do `T extends Number` to get close.

Comment: I want to make methods that work on arrays of Integer, or Long, and other methods on other types, shouldn't I check them in my method to know if what I'm doing is right or wrong?

Comment: But then, what if I want to make a method for arrays of `String`s, if `T extends Number`?

Comment: If you want such a restriction like `if (T instanceof Integer)` then it means that your class shouldn't be generic at all.

Comment: may be u should extend ur class to add for a more specific class MyLongArray extends MyArray<Long>

Comment: `sumOfElms` is not applicable to any type! In place create `apply` or `forEach` with a callback to scan all elements and apply a specific method, like a number summation or a string concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your constructor in this way:

```
public MyArray (Class<T> clazz) {
    elms = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz,INITIAL_SIZE);
    size = 0;
}
```

And while creating the `object` of `MyArray` use the following code:

```
MyArray<Integer> myArray = new MyArray<Integer>(Integer.class);
```

**UPDATE**
Further if you want to make your method to work depending upon the type of `elms` then you can work as follows:

```
public void doSomething()
{
 if (elms instanceof Integer[])
 {
   ....
 }
}
```

Comment: @aizen92: `Array.newInstance` Creates a new array with the specified component type and dimensions and returns a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Vishal K solution

> You can change your constructor in this way:
>
> ```
>     public MyArray (Class<T> clazz) {
>        elms = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz,INITIAL_SIZE);
>        size = 0;
>     }
> ```
>
> And while creating the object of MyArray use the following code:
>
> ```
>     MyArray<Integer> myArray = new MyArray<Integer>(Integer.class);
> ```

You want to make this non generic method in a generic class so u have to take other strategy, instanceof is ugly.

```
public T sumOfElms () {
    if (T instanceof Integer) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

u have to extend this class to have functionality (inheritance or composition) like this

```
public class MyLongArray extends MyArray<Long> {

   public Long sumOfElms () {
      //code here
   }

}
```

or by Composition

```
public class MyLongArrayComposed {

   private MyArray<Long> myArray;

   public Long sumOfElms () {
      //code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyArray<T> {

   ...

   private T[] elms;
   private int size;

   ...
   public boolean forEach( ArrayItemFct<T> fct ) {
      for( T t item ) {
         if( ! fct( item )) {
            return false;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
}

class Summation extends ArrayItemFct<Integer> {

   public long sum = 0L;

   @Override boolean fct( Integer item ) {
      this.sum += item;
   }
}
```

usage 1:

```
MyArray< Integer > array = new MyArray<>();
... // add items
Summation summation = new Summation();
array.forEach( summation );
long sum = summation.sum;
```

usage 2:

```
MyArray< String > array = new MyArray<>();
... // add items
Concatenation concatenation = new Concatenation();
array.forEach( concatenation );
String concat = concatenation.concat;
```